# Who are the characters in this collage on DeviantArt by user KielDaMan?

Tags: comics, anime, cartoon, character-identification

I came across this massive collage on DeviantArt by user KielDaMan, filled with over a thousand different characters from cartoons, anime, movies, video games, and other pop culture: https://www.deviantart.com/kieldaman/gallery/59727672/fun-character-collage

Most of them I already knew straight away, but others I couldn't quite put my finger on. The artist didn't give a full list of who all these characters are, so I was on my own in terms of research. With the help from Google Lens and my own intellect, I was able to find *most* of the characters I didn't already recognize, but not all of them. I've even tried getting a hold of the artist to see if he could tell me who they are, but to no avail.

So tell me, does anyone know who *any* of these characters are?

[image: collage by KielDaMan]

[image: collage by KielDaMan]

Comment: Is the first one on the fourth row Spy?

Comment: I see Mr. Bean's teddy bear; I think

Comment: Second from the left in the fourth row down appears to be George Wilson, from Dennis the Menace.

Comment: OP threatened to release a spreadsheet with all the characters and locations. They don't seem to have posted it though; https://www.reddit.com/r/wimmelbilder/comments/v1nhj0/20_years_in_the_making_15_pencil_drawing_collages/?q=excel&type=comment

Comment: To the right of George Wilson is, I think, one of the snowmen from *Calvin and Hobbes*. 
First image on the sixth row is Tetsujin from the *Tekken* series.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into the question; the answer appears below.

Comment: Could you please post the full collage, not just these excerpts?

Comment: I added a link to the gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Ongoing list:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unknown | A [mouse](https://garfield.fandom.com/wiki/Mice) from *Garfield* | One of the [101 Dalmatians](https://101dalmatians.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_101_Dalmatians:_The_Puppies) | Unknown | The older version of [Sophie Hatter](https://ghibli.fandom.com/wiki/Sophie_Hatter) from *Howl's Moving Castle* |
| Unknown | Unknown | [Kotaro](https://cyborgkurochan.fandom.com/wiki/Kotaro) from *Cyborg Kuro-chan* | [Yoda](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yoda), Unknown, and Calvin |  |
| Unknown | [Rocky](https://chickenrun.fandom.com/wiki/Rocky) from *Chicken Run* and Unknown | Unknown | Unknown | [Hawthorne](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Hawthorne_(Sherman%27s_Lagoon)) from *Sherman's Lagoon* |
| [The Black Spy](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/The_Spies_(Spy_vs._Spy)) from Spy vs. Spy | [Mr. Wilson](https://menace.fandom.com/wiki/George_Wilson) from *Dennis the Menace* (US) | A snowman from *Calvin and Hobbes* | [Turtle](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Turtle) from Dragon Ball |  |
| Unknown | Mr. Bean's [teddy bear](https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/i/d6a40595-4d77-4963-8817-7a5e92045c44/dbz8f77-b16f20d3-2f22-4545-857a-e5794415475a.png) | Unknown | [Goemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goemon_Ishikawa_XIII) from Lupin III |  |
| [Mokujin](https://tekken.fandom.com/wiki/Mokujin) from *Tekken* and a Pea Shooter from *Plants vs. Zombies* | Unknown | Unknown |  |  |
| Unknown | Unknown | [Grifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grifter_(character)) from *WildC.A.T.S.* | Unknown |  |
| [Tricero](https://dinosaucers.fandom.com/wiki/Tricero) from *Dinosaucers* | Peebo, the assistant robot from *[Bioman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choudenshi_Bioman)* | Unknown | Unknown |  |

Comment: A considerable number of these are not scifi or fantasy characters.

Comment: I think the UFO character in the first line is from *Non Sequitur*

Comment: The black spy, Dalmatian, and snowman aren't exact matches design-wise. Also, last I checked, the artist hasn't seen Howl's Moving Castle, so it can't be that.

Comment: I think that the bottom row, item 3, is one of the Angry Birds, but I couldn't swear as to which one.

Comment: No, that character has insect legs.

Comment: @Macaronow Some of the designs aren't that show-accurate if you look at the complete picture on reddit. After seeing a Sonic that looks like Sanic, a more hman looking Oloong and many other odd ones (see Lupin, Tenchi and so on) I would not be surprised if the first one on row three in the question was actually FRED from Scooby-Doo

Comment: Also... WHY would anyone with an heart choose THAT Robin scene?

Comment: @SPArcheon Which Robin scene?

Comment: @Clockwork Full image, not shown here (see the reddit link in the question comments). The full image includes multiple One Piece characters. And for Robin the author picked the iconic crying scene at Enies Lobby.

Comment: @SPArcheon Ah, I thought you were talking about Robin getting clubbed with a crowbar by the Joker in Batman Red Hood

Comment: 1 Across, 4 Down and 2 Across, 3 Down look like they're from the same thing. I'd initially thought 1A4D was just a fairly off-model Black Spy and hadn't noticed 2A3D, but since 2A3D doesn't have the distinctive black eyes (originally sunglasses), I'm not so sure anymore. I also can't find any version of Spy vs. Spy with the same rounded-looking appearance and small hats.

Comment: The "mouse from *Garfield*" looks nothing like the linked image, but does look an awful lot like Grommet from *Wallace & Grommet*.